# how to terminate msi installation using vbscript custom action

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I have one condition , if it true MSi installation/Uninstallation should terminate. How can i implement through vbscript in custom action. ?

anybody assist me.

Comment: You don't need script to do that. Use whatever tool you are using to create a type 19 custom action and terminate the install with the message specified there when your condition is set.

Answer (score 1):

[Return Values of JScript and VBScript Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371254(v=vs.85).aspx)

msiDoActionStatusNoAction 0 Action not executed.

msiDoActionStatusSuccess IDOK = 1 Action completed successfully.

msiDoActionStatusUserExit IDCANCEL = 2 Premature termination by user.

msiDoActionStatusFailure IDABORT = 3 Unrecoverable error. Returned if there is an error during 
parsing or execution of the JScript or VBScript.

msiDoActionStatusSuspend IDRETRY = 4 Suspended sequence to be resumed later.

msiDoActionStatusFinished IDIGNORE = 5 Skip remaining actions. Not an error.

```
Function MyVBScriptCA()

    If Session.Property("CustomErrorStatus") <> "0" Then
        'return error
        MyVBScriptCA = 3
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' return success
    MyVBScriptCA = 1
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Also consider reading [VBScript (and Jscript) MSI CustomActions suck](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx).